# Python: How to find the value that separates 2 different clusters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, svm, scatter-plot

I am applying an unsupervised learning algorithm for building an anomaly detection using OneClass SVM method and then plotted it to visualize how it looks.

I got 2 clusters: one red and the other blue. The red cluster corresponding to 1 (not an anomaly) and the blue cluster having a value of -1 (anomaly).

What I would like is to obtain the exact value at which both the clusters get separated.

**My Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing

data = pd.read_excel('gpmd.xlsx', header = 0)
X = data.loc[:, ['ContextID','BacksGas_Flow_sccm']]

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X.values[:,[1]])

from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

ocsvm = OneClassSVM(nu = 0.05, kernel = 'rbf', gamma = 'scale')
y_ocsvm1 = ocsvm.fit_predict(X_minmax[:,[0]])

plt.scatter(X.values[y_ocsvm1 == 1, 0], X_minmax[y_ocsvm1 == 1, 0], c = 'red', label = 'cluster1')
plt.scatter(X.values[y_ocsvm1 == -1, 0], X_minmax[y_ocsvm1 == -1, 0], c = 'blue', label = 'cluster2')
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(X_minmax[:,[0]]), max(X_minmax[:,[0]]), 0.03))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The graph I obtained after running this code is:

[image: scatter plot]

From just looking at the picture, we can roughly say that the red cluster is separated from the blue cluster at a value between 0.72 and 0.75.
I would like to know if there is a way to know the exact value where these two clusters get separated.

**Edit 1**

In the picture below we can see that a green line separates both the clusters(roughly) and I would kind of like to find such a line and its corresponding y-axis value
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Hey, @Justice_Lords. Not exactly. It just gives us the parameters. What I want is to know at which value of y-axis, both the clusters get separated

Comment: Okay, I have been searching about this, the problem is documentation exists for plotting hyperplane of linear kernels and nonlinear kernels for supervised approaches. Here we are dealing with unsupervised approaches. There is function `decision_function()` for One class SVM, It gives the distance(not absolute as we use non linear) from the hyperplane. Using that distance maybe you can try to know where the hyperplane lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion by @Justice_lords was what I was looking for. `Decision_function()` worked for me.